# R in jupyter, install windows fonts

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, fonts, jupyter

I have to design some graphs. I use R in jupyter (anaconda python 3.5), implemented with r-essentials. I now want to utilize our inhouse font, which is installed as windows font style.

Therefore, I used:

```
font_import(paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, pattern = NULL);
```

in jupyter. This command wants a promt confirmation, which is skipped (exit) by jupyter. Is there a chance to auto-answer/force that in jupyter? Alternatively, how can i install my windows fonts into the R-environment of Anaconda python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too stupid here, the command itself has an attribute "prompt" which can be set on FALSE. Sorry.